# AVL tree backtracking insert/delete actions - time efficiency

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, avl-tree

I have been trying to think about this program for the past few days. Would appreciate any opinion.

---

Hypothetically let's say I have a **stack** that has all the last actions that were made to a specific AVL tree. (Including pointers to all the nodes)

There are 2 kind of actions that I want to be able to revert -

1) insert - inserts it into the tree and maintains balance (pushes the action info into the stack)

2) delete - gets a node and removes the reference from the tree (pushes the action info into the stack)

After both actions there will be rebalancing. (Ain't the issue)

---

***My question is this***
- How efficient can we do backtracking of the deletion act & insertion act?

---

***For insertion:***

I am given a pointer to the needed nodes and case number for the "insertion type".

From my prospective **worse case** would be when you need to remove the node and do the "double" rotation to balance the tree again. Basically O(1).

**For deletion:**

I am given a pointer to the needed nodes and case number for the "deletion type".

From my prospective **worse case** would be when you need to re balance the tree h times after you remove the node.
Basically O(log(n))

Am I missing something?
Another thing that confuses me would be Omega analysis here, how can we even consider Omega here? Isn't it the same?

Thanks, have a lovely day.